# How prevent countdown timer from resetting when webpage is refreshed?

Tags: javascript, timer

I am designing a website and I integrated a 10 minute countdown timer that starts when the web-page is loaded, using JavaScript. However, since I am more of a designer than a developer, I don't know how to edit the JavaScript code to make it so that the timer does not restart when the webpage is reloaded. I know I have to store the users cookies, and I've searched online, but the javascript code didnt work when I inserted the code. Would anyone here be able to help me out?

```js
const FULL_DASH_ARRAY = 283;
const WARNING_THRESHOLD = 10;
const ALERT_THRESHOLD = 5;

const COLOR_CODES = {
  info: {
    color: "green"
  },
  warning: {
    color: "orange",
    threshold: WARNING_THRESHOLD
  },
  alert: {
    color: "red",
    threshold: ALERT_THRESHOLD
  }
};
<?php
  $timelimit = $rangewaktu;
?>
const TIME_LIMIT = <?php echo $timelimit ?>;
let timePassed = 0;
let timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT;
let timerInterval = null;
let remainingPathColor = COLOR_CODES.info.color;

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
<div class="base-timer">
  <svg class="base-timer__svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g class="base-timer__circle">
      <circle class="base-timer__path-elapsed" cx="50" cy="50" r="45"></circle>
      <path
        id="base-timer-path-remaining"
        stroke-dasharray="283"
        class="base-timer__path-remaining ${remainingPathColor}"
        d="
          M 50, 50
          m -45, 0
          a 45,45 0 1,0 90,0
          a 45,45 0 1,0 -90,0
        "
      ></path>
    </g>
  </svg>
  <span id="base-timer-label" class="base-timer__label">${formatTime(
    timeLeft
  )}</span>
</div>
`;

startTimer();

function onTimesUp() {
  clearInterval(timerInterval);
}

function startTimer() {
  timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
    timePassed = timePassed += 1;
    timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT - timePassed;
    document.getElementById("base-timer-label").innerHTML = formatTime(
      timeLeft
    );
    setCircleDasharray();
    setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft);
    
    if (timeLeft === 0) {
      onTimesUp(location.replace('test'));
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function formatTime(time) {
  const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
  let seconds = time % 60;

  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = `0${seconds}`;
  }

  return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}

function setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft) {
  const { alert, warning, info } = COLOR_CODES;
  if (timeLeft <= alert.threshold) {
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.remove(warning.color);
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.add(alert.color);
  } else if (timeLeft <= warning.threshold) {
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.remove(info.color);
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.add(warning.color);
  }
}

function calculateTimeFraction() {
  const rawTimeFraction = timeLeft / TIME_LIMIT;
  return rawTimeFraction - (1 / TIME_LIMIT) * (1 - rawTimeFraction);
}

function setCircleDasharray() {
  const circleDasharray = `${(
    calculateTimeFraction() * FULL_DASH_ARRAY
  ).toFixed(0)} 283`;
  document
    .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
    .setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", circleDasharray);
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

**strong text**

Comment: Generally, you'd store a timestamp somewhere (cookies, localStorage, server-side, etc.) that represents the end time for your countdown. Your timer (setTimeout, setInterval) checks the current time against this end time to determine how much is left and use that to do whatever notifications you need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a track of the current time before the page reloads, you can approach this with cookies, localStorage or server-side.

Here is a 1-minute countdown timer example with cookies. I am using Node.js for server-side though, but since there isn't much server-side code I hope you'll get the idea anyway.

**Server-side**

```
router.get('/test', (req, res)=>{
   res.render('test', {
      time: req.headers.cookie ? req.headers.cookie.split('time=')[1] : 59 // No cookies = first time loading the page, else get current time value
   })
});
```

**Client-side**

```
<div id="timer"></div>
<script>
    let seconds='<%= time %>';
    let timer;
    function countDown(){
        if(seconds < 60){
            document.getElementById("timer").innerText = seconds;
        }
        if(seconds>0){
            seconds--;
            document.cookie = `time=${seconds}`; // update cookie after each second
        }else{
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }
    if(!timer){
        timer = window.setInterval(()=>{ 
        countDown();
        }, 1000);
    }
    document.getElementById("timer").innerText='<%= time %>';
</script>
```

I used **ejs** templating language to be able to pass some variables to HTML before it's rendered such as the current time value in this example.

You can do the same with just cookies, doing like:

`res.cookie('time', req.headers.cookie ? req.headers.cookie.split('time=')[1] : 59);`

on the server-side and then on the client-side replace the ejs variable `'<%= time %>'` with `document.cookie`.

Hope this at least gives you more clarity about the workflow.